# Getting href using beautiful soup with different methods

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I'm trying to scrape a website. I learned to scrape from two resources: one used `tag.get('href')` to get the href from an `a` tag, and one used `tag['href']` to get the same. As far as I understand it, they both do the same thing. But when I tried this code:

```
link_list = [l.get('href') for l in soup.find_all('a')]
```

it worked with the `.get` method, but not with the dictionary access way.

```
link_list = [l['href'] for l in soup.find_all('a')]
```

This throws a `KeyError`. I'm very new to scraping, so please pardon if this is a silly one.

Edit - Both of the methods worked for the find method instead of find_all.

Comment: It's two different methods, if `key` exists in dict - it works same, but if `key` not in your dict - than `l.get` returns default value(https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and `l[key]` raised KeyError

Answer (score 5):

You may let `BeautifulSoup` *find the links with existing `href` attributes only*.
    test

You can do it in two common ways, via `find_all()`:

```
link_list = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
link_list = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HTML-string does not have a "href"?
For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


doc_html = """<a class="vote-up-off" title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear">up vote</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_html, 'html.parser')
ahref = soup.find('a')
ahref.get('href')
```

Nothing will happen, but

```
ahref['href']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/sergey/.virtualenvs/soup_example/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
'href'
```

Comment: No, that 'a' tag had a 'href' for sure. i forgot to mention the website i'm scraping. here is the link https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/